# How to navigate?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Say I create an HTML file with two `.page` on it. In the first `.page`, I'd like to have a link to the second `.page`.

Is there a way to navigate between pages without having to write my own JS? This seems to suggest I do have to write JS: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/navigation/.

However, I'd would rather set an `id` attribute for one of the pages, then maybe define some data attribute in the link to tell jQuery mobile where to go. Possible?

I'd also like to specify what kind of transition effect to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use standard anchor links, just give an id to your page and set the transition via the data attribute

```
<a href="#page2" data-transition="flip">Link to Page 2</a>
```